# How to display archive posts from one category only in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to edit archive.php. I have tried using plugins like kwebble, but they don't work. They showing all posts from that specific category without monthly archive.
What I'd want is that on the sidebar , I want the archives to display links to monthly posts for all months before the current month. It's going to look just like any ordinary archives in the sidebar, except that when the user clicks on a month e.g. "January 2013", the posts for the specific category are only shown and the rest are excluded.
Thanks in advance.